# SAS error exporting to MS Access: System Resources Exceeded

Tags: ms-access, sas

I have 3 SAS datasets that are exported to MS Access as 3 tables in a new database as part of an automated weekly process. The datasets are about 1.5 million records each, and total to about 670Mb.

I haven't been able to figure out why, but SAS fails to export the data pretty frequently, giving me this error when it does:

```
ERROR: CLI execute error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] System resource exceeded.
```

The code that produces that error (runs once for each dataset, changing just the data name and data table for each one):

```
PROC EXPORT DATA = &_dataname_.
    OUTTABLE = "&_datatable_."
    DBMS = ACCESSCS REPLACE;
DATABASE = "&_databasename_..mdb";
RUN;
```

I know Access has a 2gb limit, but the datasets aren't anywhere near that size. I also saw that there's a record limit of something like 32,000 records, but I can frequently export many more than that without any issue, so I'm not sure that's the reason either. But, I do suspect that it must have something to do with the size of the data since it will often only throw that error after adding the second or third table to the database.

So, my question comes it two parts:

- Why is this happening?
- Without using a different database like MySQL, how can I fix the problem/work around it?

Thank you for any help you can provide. It's much appreciated!

Comment: What Access version are you using?

Comment: Access 2010, and everything is saved with the .mdb extension.

Comment: Bit of a long shot but this might help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2726928

Answer (score 0):

This is not a record limit problem, but it is almost certainly too much data for Access to reasonably handle. "X" MB in SAS won't necessarily translate to "X" MB in Access. And, Access just isn't designed to handle millions of rows of data (which of course doesn't stop people from trying).

When I was regularly developing Access databases, I found that anything over 100,000 rows in a table containing say two dozen columns of employee address and contact information started to result in a performance hit.

If MySQL or SQL Server are available to you, then I'd go that route...less headaches for you in the long run and much better scalability too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I *have* to use Access; my boss has already shot down the idea of switch to a real database because so many people already have and use Access. I honestly don't think he'll be willing to make a change until something catastrophic happens.

Comment: If it's a question of end users needing Access, they can still do so while the data itself is hosted on a more appropriate platform. It's just a matter of maintaining the Access front end with a link to SQL Server or MySQL or whatever. If cost is a consideration there are plenty of free SQL platforms. Maybe do a proof of concept thing on the side and show that it can work quite nicely...

Comment: I honestly didn't know you could even do that; we usually just create the Access database, then put it in a shared drive for people to use.

Do you know of any resources that might explain how to create an Access front end with a link to a SQL Server?

Comment: Just search for "access frontend sql server backend". Assuming that your data is in SQL Server (or whatever platform) already, you'd go External Data > ODBC Database to connect to it. The benefit to doing this is that you maintain a single copy of the Access front-end somewhere, and whenever you make modifications to it the users just grab the new file. With the data in one central place you can make front-end modifications without concern for screwing the data up in any way.